# How to deploy internal MobileFirst hybrid application to dedicated Bluemix environment?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-mobilefirst

I would like to know the different approaches to deploy the locally built MobileFirst hybrid application to dedicated Bluemix environment.

I have used containers from public Bluemix environment to create worklight console to deploy wlapp and adapter files. Containers are not available in dedicated Bluemix environment.

Is there anything we can do to deploy the files in dedicated environment?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The ability to use containers in a dedicated Bluemix environment is not supported at this time.

Comment: Okay. Are there any other options to push to dedicated environment ?

Comment: I would say your options at this point in time are using the on-premise MobileFirst product or containers on public Bluemix.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct that the IBM Container Service is not yet available as part of the Bluemix Dedicated offering but we are working on making the Container Service available in the dedicated offering so stay tuned.

Dan